# Why I get "Parameter value [appa] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]"?

Tags: java, hibernate

I don't understand why I get this error. Everything seems to be right to me. 
The followings are my class definitions:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Comparable<Product>, java.io.Serializable {
//...

    protected Department department;
//...
}

public class Department implements Serializable {

    private String id;
//...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

and my HQL:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Product> findProductsByDepartment(final String deptId, String final int limit) {

    return entityManager
            .createQuery(
                    "select i from Product i left join ... where ... and i.department.id = :deptId").setParameter("deptId", deptId).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();
}
```

The exception stack points to the statement setParameter("deptId", deptId). The @Id type can be String (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html). I don't know why it expects an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Product table (in your database), because your id field must be a numeric field (I supoose). You are mapping it as a String, so you must change its type to Integer:

```
private Integer id;
//...

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: The exception is for Department, but not Product. I forgot to mention that the field in the DB table is defined as varchar(4) as  CREATE TABLE vsm_department
(
  id character varying(4) NOT NULL, ... }